# Handling DbExpress Sql Error Code 245

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I am trying to build a scheduler application for my semestre exam, and I am interogating the database if a teacher has classes in a certain week, certain day and a certain hour. Is there a way to treat Sql Error Codes in Delphi Xe2 using  DBExpress? I have a query performing my interogation(I let the users to select the parameters) on SQL Server2008, and here is the issue; If an user lets one parameter field empty, my application shows the message in the image; well this is not a user friendly way of showing error messages, so I tried to handle the exception  without any succes: this is my code that i wrote to query SQL Server:

```
with DataModule1.QueryV1 do
 Try
    Close;
    SQL.Clear; // clear command sql if there is
    SQL.Add ('SELECT * FROM OrarC WHERE IDZi =' +
    QuotedStr(LlbZiua.KeyValue)+ 'and IDInterval=' + QuotedStr(LlbIntOrar.KeyValue) +
     'and IDSala='+ QuotedStr(EdtIDSala.Text)+ EdtSaptamana.Text);
    Open;
  except
    on E:TDBXError do begin
      showmessage('Error!');
    end;
  End;
```

on E:TDBXError I have also tried E:EDataBaseError and the result is the same; It would be good to handle the error by the SqlErrorCode returned but I don`t know how to get that.
[image]

Comment: It is better to use parameters to the query than literal strings. Maybe one of your strings holds a value different to what you expected. What is the error text in the message above? The picture is too small for me to read the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your program under the debugger and observe the actual class of the exception that's raised, or you can get the exception class at runtime with something like:

```
  ..
except on E: Exception do
  ShowMessage(E.ClassName);
end;
```

If it is indeed a `TDBXError` then you could use for example

```
uses
  dbxcommon;

except
  on E: TDBxError do begin
    if (E.ErrorCode = TDBXErrorCodes.InvalidArgument) then
      ..
```

But as far as I can see 245 is not one of `TDBXErrorCodes`, so possibly you've got an other exception. If it's an `EDatabaseError` there's nothing much to do, since the class does not have an error code field.

Not quite relevant but also see [Data.DBXCommon.TDBXConnection.OnErrorEvent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBXCommon.TDBXConnection.OnErrorEvent) to be able to manage dbexpress exceptions at a central location.